# how can i access the variable of class with input in python

Tags: python, class, oop, class-variables

**CODE:**

```
class Abc:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 4

    def abc(self,x , y):
        return x + y
def main():
    p = input("Enter the variable name:") # a
    q = input("Enter the variable name:") # b
    Abc.abc(Abc.p, Abc.q)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**QUESTION?**

let say i have this code and I want to access the variable of class according to user input.for example when I run this code it will ask for the values and I give the values "a" and "b" so now p = a and q = b so how can I access the variable of class with this p and q ?

**OUTPUT/ERROR:**
Enter the variable name:a

Enter the variable name:b
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/untitled2.py", line 22, in 
main()

File "/home/untitled2.py", line 19, in main
Abc.abc(Abc.p, Abc.q)

AttributeError: type object 'Abc' has no attribute 'p'

Comment: What do you expect `Abc.p` to do? `p` is not defined in class `Abc`.

Comment: I think you need to follow a basic tutorial on how to use Python classes.

Comment: I don't understand what *problem you hope to solve* by doing this. You want the user to type `a` and the `Abc` class to decide that this should be *translated into* the value `2`? First off, why? Second, did you consider just using a `dict` to create such a mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr()` if the name of the attribute is in a variable.

```
getattr(Abc, p)
```